# ajax error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, laravel

i used ajax to pass data form to laravel controller
But when i run my code , it alway return error (Internal Server Error)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSave").click(function(e){
        var _token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        // var selPartners = $("input[name='selPartners'] option:selected").val();
        var selPartners= $('#selPartners :selected').text();
        var txtDescription = $("input[name='txtDescription'] ").val();
        var txtPrice = $("input[name='txtPrice']").val();
        var txtWarrantyDate = $("input[name='txtWarrantyDate']").val();
        var itemImage = $('#itemImage').prop('files')[0];
        // var selItems =$("input[name='selItems']").val();
        var selItems= $('#selItems :selected').text();
        var x ={_token:_token, selPartners:selPartners, selItems:selItems, txtDescription:txtDescription, txtPrice:txtPrice, txtWarrantyDate:txtWarrantyDate, itemImage:itemImage}
        // console.log(x);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/additem",
            type:'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: {_token:_token, selPartners:selPartners, selItems:selItems, txtDescription:txtDescription, txtPrice:txtPrice, txtWarrantyDate:txtWarrantyDate, itemImage:itemImage},
            success: function(data) {

                if($.isEmptyObject(data.error)){
                    console.log('ok');

                }else{
                    console.log('failed');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

At controller just has:

```
return response()->json(['error'=>'failed']);
```

Comment: It's doing what you told it to do. You're responding with `{"error":"failed"}`, which your JavaScript processes and does the `console.log('failed');` bit.

Comment: can you show me the error .. probably it's routing error

Comment: Please share the server side code